# Minimizing long equation with hyperbolic functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

In physics book that I am reading it is said that minimizing the expression
$$\phi =  - N T k \log (2 \cosh(H \beta)) - \frac{J N}{2} z \tanh^2(H \beta)
+ H N \tanh(H \beta) $$
with respect to $H$ gives self-consistent expression:
$$H_0=Jz\tanh(\beta H_0)$$

where $\beta=\frac{1}{kT}$. I want to obtain this by myself. My attempt is:
$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial H}=0$
where 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial H} &= - N T \beta k \tanh(H \beta) 
+ J N \beta z (\tanh^3(H \beta) - \tanh(H \beta)) \\
& \hspace{5mm} + N \left(\frac{H \beta}{\cosh^{2}{\left (H \beta \right )}} + \tanh (H \beta ) \right)
\end{align}

Further I don't know what to do. Expression just seems too complicated. Maybe someone can advice me what to do next :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting ffrom
$$\phi =  - N T k \log (2 \cosh(H \beta)) - \frac{J N}{2} z \tanh^2(H \beta)
+ H N \tanh(H \beta)$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d \phi}{dH} &= - \frac{N}{\beta} \cdot \beta \tanh(\beta H) - J N \beta z \tanh(\beta H) \, sech^{2}(\beta H) + H N \beta sech^{2}(\beta H) + N \tanh(\beta H) \\
&= N \beta ( H - J z \, \tanh(\beta H) ) \, sech^{2}(\beta H) \\
&= N \beta \, (H - J z \, \tanh(\beta H) ) \, (1 - \tanh^{2}(\beta H) ).
\end{align}
Since the minimum value is defined by 
$$ \frac{d \phi}{d H} = 0 $$
then either 
$$ H_{0} = J z \, \tanh(\beta H_{0}) $$
or 
$$ H_{0} = \frac{1}{\beta} \, \tanh^{-1}(1).$$